# wpbackery visual composer 5.4.7 front end editor not working only showing logo

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-composer

here is the error i am getting in chrome console when try to open front end editor

I have latest wp 4.9.8 version 
I have visual composer 5.4.7 version, Kindly check and help me to fix it

Note: my backend editor working fine only getting issue in frontend editor

```
Uncaught TypeError: vc.frame_window.jQuery is not a function
    at vc.ShortcodesBuilder.buildFromContent (frontend-editor.min.js?ver=5.5.2:1)
    at Object.vc.build (frontend-editor.min.js?ver=5.5.2:1)
    at frontend-editor.min.js?ver=5.5.2:1
```

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The problem was caused by the "Rocket Loader" option in Cloudflare. This is under the "Speed" section. Once I deactivated that option, that error disappeared.
That Rocket Loader option is meant to speed up the paint of files containing JavaScript. However, it doesn't seem to work well with Visual Composer (vc).
I submitted a ticket to Cloudflare support, I hope they fix this soon.

Comment: Thank you, been trying to figure this out for ages! I guess the Auto Minify options are good to enable?

Answer (score 0):

Update your version to the newest one. there is some kind of conflict as in the error, the version mentioned is the latest and not the 4.9.8.

Comment: wordpress version or visualcomposer?

Comment: Visual composer